# How to distribute matrix into inverse of sum of two matrices

Tags: matrix, matrix-inverse

For matrices A, B, and C, is there a way to bring the C into the inverse here:

```
 (A+B)^(-1)*C
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming, which is what [so] is all about.

Answer (score -1):

((C)^(-1)A + C^(-1)B)^(-1), I believe.